# Trouble figuring out how to add and convert int values from one 2d array to a boolean 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having a hard time trying to take int elements in a two dimensional array and making it a boolean two dimensional array based on certain criteria.

elements range between 1-3.
if the element is a 3 it is false.
if the neighboring elements, excluding the 'center' element, have a total sum of 15 or above it is false.
anything else is to be true.

I get this error message:
"true | Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 5
at L10upp9.main(L10upp9.java:40)"

Would appreciate any help understanding this!

```
    int[][] inputArray = {{1,1,2,3,3},
                          {2,1,1,2,3},
                          {3,2,2,1,2},
                          {3,3,3,3,3},};


    boolean[][] outputArray = new boolean[4][5];

    int sum = 0;


    for (int row=0; row<inputArray.length ; row++ ) {
      for (int col=0; col<inputArray[row].length ; col++ ) {

        //System.out.printf("%4d", inputArray[row][col]);

        if (inputArray[row][col] == 3) {

          outputArray[row][col] = false;

        }else {
          outputArray[row][col] = true;
        }


        //neighbouring elements
        for (int i=-1; i<=1 ; i++ ) {
          for (int j=-1; j<=1 ; j++ ) {

            if((row+i>=0) && (row+i<inputArray.length)
              && (col+j>=0) && (col+j<inputArray[row].length)
              && !(i==0 && j==0)){

              sum+=inputArray[i][j];
              if(sum>=15) {

                  outputArray[row][col]=false;

              }else {
                  outputArray[row][col]=true;
              }
```

Comment: What’s the value of sum when you start summing the neighbors of the second element?

Comment: I mean if you look at the value of sum at that point I. The execution of your program, either with the debugger, printing it out, or just executing your program on paper, what is it?

Comment: @tgdavies Do you mean the second 1 in the first row? Sum should be 0 regardless the element whos neighbors are being added. Since it starts at i=-1, it should be the left-up diagonal element. Out of bounds spaces should be ignored

Comment: "... at that point in the execution of..."

Comment: That is, I'm asking what the value is, not what it "should be".

Comment: @tgdavies I understand what you mean now. but I'm afraid I might be too tired to figure even that out. I've been up all night. Even things that were clear earlier are confusing to me right now. Why did I write row+i in the second if statement? Nevermind. I'm going to bed. Thank you for your help! I think It'll help when I wake up.

Comment: Next time you post a question about code that doesn’t seem to behave right, please include a precise description of what issue you are observing. If you are getting wrong output, quote the correct output and the observed output in your question. So we can understand what the question is and what to look for in your code. Thanks.

Comment: BTW I think you are testing the sum too early. Your `if(sum>=15)` should probably go elsewhere. And: Learn to use a debugger. You need it.